# SQLite.swift - ObservableObject - table object is not correct - update / delete has an issue

Tags: ios, sqlite, swiftui

I have created an issue in GitHub project.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/1114

I use the link https://adnan-tech.com/create-read-update-and-delete-from-sqlite-swift-swift-ui/ to understand, how I have to use SQLite in my swiftui app.

All is fine with this example but with every call of the class, the init methode is called.

Therefore I switched to an observable class. So the init is called once at the app start.
With this change, the insert is working but the delete function failed with error
*"ORDER BY without LIMIT on DELETE (code: 1)"* as well the update function too.

I found out that the table object is the problem. When I add the following line in the update / delete function

> self.users = Table("users")

All is working but I don't understand why.

self.users is the class variable which contains the user records.
When I check self.users count, all is correct. But why I have to add the assignment in the update / delete function again.

Here are my whole code.

```
//
//  SQLiteManager.swift
//  SQLiteDemo
//
//  Created by sven on 20.02.22.
//
// Documentatio : https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#custom-sql-functions
// Tutorial     : https://adnan-tech.com/create-read-update-and-delete-from-sqlite-swift-swift-ui/

import Foundation

// import library
import SQLite

final class SQLiteManager : ObservableObject {
    
    // sqlite instance
    private var db: Connection!
    
    // table instance
    private var users: Table!
    
    // columns instances of table
    private var id: Expression<Int64>!
    private var name: Expression<String>!
    private var email: Expression<String>!
    private var age: Expression<Int64>!
    
    // constructor of this class
    init () {
        
        // exception handling
        do {
            
            // path of document directory
            let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] // .first! also possible
            let sqliteFile = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("db").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
            
            // creating database connection
            self.db = try Connection("\(sqliteFile)")
        
            // creating table object
            self.users = Table("users")
            
            // create instances of each column
            self.id = Expression<Int64>("id")
            self.name = Expression<String>("name")
            self.email = Expression<String>("email")
            self.age = Expression<Int64>("age")
            
            // if not exist, create the table
            try self.db.run(self.users.create(ifNotExists: true) { (t) in
                t.column(self.id, primaryKey: .autoincrement)
                t.column(self.name)
                t.column(self.email, unique: true)
                t.column(self.age)
            })
            
        } catch {
            // show error message if any
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    public func insertUser(nameValue: String, emailValue: String, ageValue: Int64) {
        do {
            // No assignment (self.users = Table("users")) required
            try self.db.run(self.users.insert(self.name <- nameValue, self.email <- emailValue, self.age <- ageValue))
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    // function to update user
    public func updateUser(idValue: Int64, nameValue: String, emailValue: String, ageValue: Int64) {
        do {
            self.users = Table("users") // ==> need the assignment again to avoid issue
            
            // get user using ID
            let user: Table = self.users.filter(self.id == idValue)
            
            // run the update query
            try self.db.run(user.update(self.name <- nameValue, self.email <- emailValue, self.age <- ageValue))
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    // function to delete user
    public func deleteUser(idValue: Int64) {
        do {
            self.users = Table("users") // ==> need the assignment again to avoid issue
            
            // get user using ID
            let user: Table = self.users.filter(id == idValue)
            
            // run the delete query
            try db.run(user.delete())
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
I have a function which gets all the users. Inside this function I do a sort / order of the users. This sort / order is the problem. Now, I do it in another way and now all is working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).